# using hard link with kate editor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kate

I have problem in working with link command in linux mint.
I made file1 and add a new hard link to that file :

```
link file1 file2
```

I know when I change the contents of file1 , file2 should change too.
and when I edit file1 with vim or add text to it with redirections it works well but when
I edit file1 with kate editor then it's like that the editor break the link of file2! and after that when
I change the contents of file1 with kate or vim,... file 2 will never change any more.
what's the problem?

Comment: `kate` is likely working on a copy of `file1`, and instead of opening `file1` and writing the contents of the copy to it, just performing the equivalent of `mv tmp file1`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the Kate developers. The issue is as follows: Whenever Kate saves, it does so by saving into a temporary file in the same folder, and on success just does a move to the desired location.

This move operation is exactly what destroys your hard link: first, the hard link is removed, then the temporary file is renamed.

While this avoids data loss, it also has its own problems as you experience. We are tracking this bug here:

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358457 - QSaveFile: Kate removes a hard link to file when opening a file with several hard links

And in addition, QSaveFile also has two further issues, tracked here:

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333577 - QSaveFile: kate changes file owner
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354405 - QSaveFile: Files are unlinked upon save

The solution would be to just directly write in all these corner cases, then we could avoid this trouble at the expense of loosing data in case of a system crash, so it's a tradeoff. To fix this, we need to patch Qt, which noone did so far.

Comment: Update: Given the many issues of QSaveFile, Kate now uses simple direct write again, starting from KDE Frameworks 5.50.

Answer (score 1):

Different programs save files in different ways. At least two come to mind:

- open existing file and overwrite its content
- create temporary file, write new content there, then somehow replace original file with new one (remove old file and rename new one; or rename old file, rename new file, then remove old file; or use system function to swap files content (in fact, swap names of files), then remove old file; or ...)

Judging from its current source code, Kate is using the latter approach (using QSaveFile in the end, with [direct write fallback](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html#setDirectWriteFallback) though). Why? Usually, to make file saving more or less atomic, and also to make sure that saving won't result in errors caused by e.g. lack of free space (although this also means that it uses the space of sum of old and new file sizes when saving).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Kate on Linux Mint but I have noticed issues which lead me to suspect you may have come across a "bug".

Here are two 'similar' issues with hard links that have been reported.

[Bug 316240 - KSaveFile: Kate/kwrite makes a copy of a file while editing a hard link](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316240#c6)

["Hard link not supported" with NTFS on Linux #3241](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/3241)